# How to make a layout fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-statusbar, android-fullscreen

Hello StackOverflowers.

I have a this layout:

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
......
    >
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

I just set the primary color alpha to 00 and the status bar has no color. What I like is that it goes full screen and under the status bar.

I made another activity, but it is a ConstraintLayout not as DrawerLayout as in the above case. I also set the android:fitsSystemWindows="true". but it just will not go full screen.

Here is the code:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/splashScreenLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".SplashScreen">

     <ImageView>
.......
    <>
```

this is the result:
[image]

I could also use DrawerLayout to achieve this effect, but I do not need a drawer in that activity.
Is there a more professional approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
I had to set android:fitsSystemWindows="false" and I added this function to may activity and called it in on create:

```
  private fun showSystemUI() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    }
```

Even the image view in my activity goes under the status bar. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

try using this in onCreate Activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: this is totally removing the action bar.